# Facebook-sdk in python: how to get information about users invited in group?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, python-3.x

When you look to the list of members of some group on Facebook, you can see some like "Added by "%username" where "username" is user who added this member to the group. I need to make a list of one group's members in such format: user1 : user2, where user 1 is a member name and user2 is user who invited him. I use facebook-sdk for python 3.4 I read graphapi reference, and in edge 'members' there is no such field like 'Added by'. Now i have something like this:

```
    import facebook
    access_token = "%token%"         
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
    members = graph.get_connections("%groupid", "")
   for member in members:
       print(member)
```

My question is where the information about "Added by somebody" is stored in GraphAPI?